# Cómo acceder a un array dentro de otro

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Estoy trabajando con una tabla en la cual quiero mostrar unos datos que estan en un array, hasta ahí bien, el problema surge cuando quiero imprimir un array que está dentro de este array, no logro itinerar sobre sus datos, lo he intentado de varias formas, una de ellas es esta, también dejo una foto del array al cual estoy intentando acceder.

[image: ][1]]
[image: esta es una de las formas que lo e]

y un console.log del array al cual quiero acceder.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas acceder al objeto directamente. No esta muy claro tu estructura de datos y voy a suponer que es de la siguiente manera.

```js
pedidos =  [
    { 
        //.... mas datos
        order: [ //...string]
    }

]
```

Con esta estructura necesitas hacer esto:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let pedido of orden.pedidos >

     //Muchos datos...
     <ion-row *ngFor="let order of pedido.order >

       {{order}}

     //... fin de tus tags
```